# Why does this check to see if user is authorized to edit a post fail for all but super admins?

Tags: user-roles, authorization

I'm trying to determine if a piece of content can be edited by a user. I would like all roles contributor and above to be authorized by a single check. Here's my code:

```
    if( empty( $post_id ) || !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) { return; }
```

Unfortunately, the only users that don't get the `return` are super admins. Any idea why?

Comment: How are you getting `$post_id`?

Comment: Re my comment @HameedullahKhan, I',m afraid I'm not sure why this isn't working. For the benefit of people experiencing a similar problem - you should check that the relevant users have the `edit_others_posts` capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the correct capability name is `edit_posts`. So the correct way of using `current_user_can` will be like following:

```
if( empty( $post_id ) || !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) { return; }
```

**UPDATE:** I have removed the wrong statement, but as the asker mentioned he would like to allow all roles of contributors and above to be authorized for that particular check, I think just checking for `edit_posts` caps is enough. Sorry for the wrong statement.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Looking at the documentation, `current_user_can` slices the arguments it's given. It sends the inputted capability and other arguments to `$current_user->has_cap()` which does something similar. This uses `map_meta_cap()` to check if user can `edit_posts` and is post author or can `edit_other_posts`. This is how WordPress deals with these situations. See `wp-includes/capabilities.php` for the relevant functions.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for pointing out the mistake. I have removed that incorrect statement.